# Check if array contains any even numbers and then show lowest even (or odd if no evens present)

Tags: swift

In a function, I want to first check if the array given contains any numbers.

If there is an even number in the array I want to show the smallest number, and if there aren't any even numbers I want to at least show the smallest odd number whilst informing the user there are no even numbers.

The issue I have run into is: if there is a lower odd number in the array than the lowest even number it will ignore the fact that there is an even number in the array.

My progress to solving this was to first be able to determine the smallest number in an array

```
func smallestNumberInArray(listOfNumbers numbers: [Int]) -> Int {
  var smallestNumber = numbers[0]
  for x in numbers {
    if x < smallestNumber {
      smallestNumber = x
    }
  }
  return smallestNumber
}
```

I then test it with `smallestNumberInArray(listOfNumbers: [33, 44, 10, 22222, 099, 83])` which prints out 10

To test the even or odd logic I simply did

```
var listOfNumbers = [200, 3, 202]
for x in listOfNumbers {
  if x % 2 == 0 {
    print("\(x)")
  }
}
```

Which printed out 200 and 202

I tried to combine this into 1 function

```
func checkSmallestEvenNumber(yourNumbers numbers: [Int]) -> String {
  var smallestNumber = numbers[0]
  var returnString = "Placeholder"

  for x in numbers {
    if x % 2 == 0 {
      if x < smallestNumber {
        smallestNumber = x
        returnString = "The smallest even number is: \(smallestNumber)"
      }
    } else {
      if x < smallestNumber && x % 2 != 0 {
        smallestNumber = x
        returnString = "No Evens, but the smallest odd is: \(smallestNumber)"
      }
    }
  }
  return returnString
}
```

So my function call `checkSmallestEvenNumber(yourNumbers: [29, 33, 55, 22, 130, 101, 99])` returns `The smallest even number is: 22` in this scenario, but if I change say the 55 to a 5 the return value is `No Evens, but the smallest odd is: 5` when I want it to be 22 still.

Comment: Your logic just replaces `returnString` with the "No Evens" text if an odd number is the smallest number, even if evens were found.  There are a number of ways to fix this - you could store the smallest even and odd numbers separately.  But given the _name_ of your function, I would consider dropping the `else` block entirely.  (If you do that, you might want to change "Placeholder" to "No evens found".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to fix it. I made some tweaks to your code

```
func checkSmallestEvenNumber(yourNumbers numbers: [Int]) -> String {
    guard !numbers.isEmpty else {
        return "Empty array"
    }
    var smallestNumber = numbers[0]
    var returnString = ""

   for x in numbers {
    if x % 2 == 0,
        (smallestNumber % 2 != 0 || x < smallestNumber) {
             smallestNumber = x
        print(smallestNumber)

             returnString = "The smallest even number is: \(smallestNumber)"
        
     } else if x < smallestNumber,
            smallestNumber % 2 != 0,
            x % 2 != 0 {
         smallestNumber = x

         returnString = "No Evens, but the smallest odd is: \(smallestNumber)"
     }
    }
    if returnString.isEmpty {
        if smallestNumber % 2 == 0 {
            returnString = "The smallest even number is: \(smallestNumber)"
        } else {
            returnString = "No Evens, but the smallest odd is: \(smallestNumber)"
        }
    }
  return returnString
}

checkSmallestEvenNumber(yourNumbers: [0, 2, 23, 55, 130, 101, 55])
```

Comment: I just tried changing the 0 to a 1 in the function call, and similarly to my code it ignores the 2 and says the lowest odd is 1

Comment: Edited the soultion `if x % 2 == 0, (smallestNumber % 2 != 0 || x < smallestNumber)` Hope this covers all test cases

Comment: i just figured it out a different way moments after you posted the change! Thank you for this solution! I think its more elegant than mine

Answer (score 4):

Take advantage of higher level functions like `filter` with predicate `isMultiple(of: 2)` and `min()`

The result must be an optional to cover the case that the input array can be empty

```
func smallestNumberInArray(listOfNumbers numbers: [Int]) -> Int? {
    if let smallestEvenNumber = numbers.filter({$0.isMultiple(of: 2)}).min() { return smallestEvenNumber }
    return numbers.min()
}

smallestNumberInArray(listOfNumbers: [29, 33, 5, 22, 130, 101, 99])
```

Alternatively – and probably more efficient – first sort the array then return the first even number or the first number which must be odd or – if the array is empty – return `nil`

```
func smallestNumberInArray(listOfNumbers numbers: [Int]) -> Int? {
    let sortedArray = numbers.sorted()
    return sortedArray.first{$0.isMultiple(of: 2)} ?? sortedArray.first
}
```

A third way is first to [partition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017524-partition) the array in even and odd numbers and get the smallest number of the slices

```
func smallestNumberInArray(listOfNumbers numbers: [Int]) -> Int? {
    var mutableNumbers = numbers
    let firstOddIndex = mutableNumbers.partition(by: {$0.isMultiple(of: 2)})
    return mutableNumbers[firstOddIndex...].min() ?? mutableNumbers[0..<firstOddIndex].min()
}
```

Comment: I doubt if sorting the array is more efficient. I make your smallestNumberInArray function to have `2•O(n)` time performance, which is simplified to be `O(n)`. The best sorting algorithms have `O(n•log(n))` time performance, which is worse than `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be throwing an error for odd numbers, not returning Strings.

```swift
extension Sequence where Element: BinaryInteger {
  func lowestEvenNumber() throws -> Element {
    switch (minima { $0.isMultiple(of: 2) }) {
    case (_, let even?):
      return even
    case (let odd?, nil):
      throw NoEvenNumbersError.onlyOdds(odd)
    case (nil, nil):
      throw NoEvenNumbersError<Element>.empty
    }
  }
}

enum NoEvenNumbersError<Integer: BinaryInteger>: Error {
  case empty
  case onlyOdds(Integer)
}
```

vadian's partitioning solution is good enough for your use case, but it's not applicable for all sequences. It should be. This is, and uses memory only for two elements:

```swift
public extension Sequence where Element: Comparable {
  /// Two minima, with the second satisfying a partitioning criterion.
  func minima(
    partitionedBy belongsInSecondPartition: (Element) -> Bool
  ) -> (Element?, Element?) {
    reduce(into: (nil, nil)) { minima, element in
      let partitionKeyPath = belongsInSecondPartition(element) ? \(Element?, Element?).1 : \.0

      if minima[keyPath: partitionKeyPath].map({ element < $0 }) ?? true {
        minima[keyPath: partitionKeyPath] = element
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I already marked @achu 's answer to be correct but as I mentioned in comments I figured it out moments after @achu answered.

Here is my less elegant solution: I separated the functionality into two functions and passed a function as a parameter in the main function.

```
func findLowestNumber(passingArray nums: [Int]) -> Int{
  var small = nums[0]
  for x in nums {
    if x < small {
      small = x
    }
  }
 return small
}
```

I will use this mini function as a passing parameter later on

```
func checkSmallestEvenNumber(yourNumbers numbers: [Int]) -> String {
  var parameterIntArray = numbers[0]
  var allEvens = [Int]()
  var str = "Placeholder"

  for x in numbers {
    if x % 2 != 0 {
      str = "No Evens, however the lowest odd is \(findLowestNumber(passingArray: numbers))"
    } else {
      allEvens.append(x)
    }
 }

if allEvens.isEmpty != true {
  str = "The lowest even is \(findLowestNumber(passingArray: allEvens))"
}

  return str
}
```

What I did first was to check if any of the numbers were even. If none were then I created a string saying such but then passed the earlier function as a parameter to at least find the lowest odd.

The main fix was if there were any evens I appended them to a new array. Within this new array I again passed the earlier function to find the lowest number.

I'm sure this could be cleaned up (without using higher functions like map etc)

Answer (score -1):

This function might not be "Swifty" (using higher order functions) but it will give a result with a single pass through the array:

```
func lowestEvenFromArray(_ intArray: [Int]) -> Int?  {
    var lowestEven: Int? = nil
    var lowestOdd: Int? = nil
    for value in intArray {
        if value.isMultiple(of: 2) {
            if value < (lowestEven ?? Int.max) {
                lowestEven = value
            }
        } else if value < (lowestOdd ?? Int.max) {
            lowestOdd = value
        }
    }
    return lowestEven ?? lowestOdd
}
```

It should be the fastest of the answers given, all of which will make at least 2 passes through the array.